# Adding Columns to Existing DataTable Programatically

Tags: spotfire

Are there any other possible ways to add columns to a data table within Spotfire, besides the method mentioned here: [Spotfire add column from python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068783/spotfire-add-column-from-python-list)? I'm asking because the method works for a particular field that I have, except when the values are NULL (obviously cannot perform a join operation on a field, which is NULL).

Comment: If the join is the problem, why not use some sort of NullIF or IsNull function  to force a value and satisfy the join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue through creating a calculated column that uses the row IDs to perform the join so the nulls would never interfere with the join.

Comment: I think it's best you close this question