# Add column to an existing spotfire table from a C# data structure

Tags: c#, spotfire, r.net

I am working on a spotfire extension where data is extracted from a spotfire table, sent to a standalone R script, and the results added as a new column. I am having trouble adding a new column to the spotfire table. After a bit of searching, the only references to adding a column were to either add a CalculatedColumn from an existing column and an expression or to convert the data to a text file data source, (the link explains how to do it using python, [How to create a data table on the fly in Spotfire via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533046/how-to-create-a-data-table-o..).). Are these the only options, is there a better way to do it? Note that i am constrained to use Spotfire 6.5, C# and the R.Net environment, i can't use TERR or Iron Python scripts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet is going to be replacing the table with your R results since you can't use any scripts to automate this.